# Forward Header Variable Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

In my current project I am forwarding some request do another micro-service, and I receive a variable in a header to identify the caller. I want to sent this in my post call to the other service. I know I can receive in my controller and add as a parameter in my methods, but I have to add this variable in all layers of my code.

Is there a way to receive this variable and send in post without passing it as variable?

My current solution is something as this:

```
public ResponseEntity foo(@RequestHeader(value = "bar", required = false) final String bar){
     fooService.post(bar);
}

public class FooService(){

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public void post(Bar bar){
        ....
        restTemplate.postForEntity(...);
        ....
    }
}
```

There are more layers, which can get messy with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I clear understand your problem but you can setup this variable in some custom context class which will store this variable and by [interceptor](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-interceptor) you can set this variable in rest template post method.